# Windows 7 64 bit Home SP1 installation fails with ERROR_NOT_FOUND message

Tags: windows-7, installation

Windows 7 SP2 installation failed many times on my laptop.

```
[HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
```

1. I ran "System Update Readiness Tool"
2. I got a list of KBxxxxx *.mum file missing in the C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log
3. I got "Element not found".

How do I recover?

---

The exact patch is "KB976932 Windows 7 Service Pack 1 for x64"

This a log line from `cbs.log`:

```
C:\Windows\Servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB974455~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1‌​.0.mum [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
```

Comment: Where did you get this "Windows 7 SP2" - can only be beta version or something non-official because there is no official SP2 for Windows 7.

Comment: Sorry Robert, the exact patch is "KB976932 Windows 7 Service Pack 1 for x64"

Comment: This a log line from cbs.log: C:\Windows\Servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB974455~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.mum [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]

Comment: OK, It is somehow similar to my problem, I will add an example to my answer

Comment: So you are installing SP1 on a PC that already has SP2 installed?, your post is confusing, you need to edit it.

Comment: Sorry Moab, the Title is wrong I will try to change it into "SP1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many files are listed as "missing" in CBS.log? If they are limited to a limited number (10 or 20). You may try to manually reinstall them, otherwise I suspect you got some unuexpected failure in the windows update, but I need some other info like Windows Event Viewer.

In any case this is the "MANUAL" procedure.

1. Manually download any of KBxxxx update from Microsoft site (example: Windows6.1-KB974455-x64.msu)
   (do not confuse Windows6.1-KBxxxxx-x64 with Windows6.1-KBxxxxx-x86 !!!)
2. Manually extract msu files into local directory: It will generate at laest one xml file and 1 .cab files
3. Manually extract files from .CAB (cabinet files): you will find the files as named in the CBS.log

That's all, just recover files from such temporary location

---

#### Example with KB978207

```
mkdir d:\tmp2
mkdir d:\tmp2\files
cd /d d:\tmp2
D:\Download\Windows6.1-KB978207-x64.msu /extract:D:\tmp2
Dir *.cab
expand -F:* D:\tmp2\Windows6.1-KB978207-x64.cab D:\tmp2\files
cd /d D:\tmp2\files
dir *.mum
dir *.cat
```

Now, recover files:

```
copy *.mum C:\Windows\servicing\Packages
copy *.cat C:\Windows\servicing\Packages
```

Repeat for all KBxxxx file missing like your KB974455. Disable antivirus software if any.

Comment: Hi Diego, can you specify better howto extract msu files ? In which directory should I restore missing files ?

Comment: I will try to recover manually, I've already found a similar solution [link](http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/68403-update-kb978637-failed-install-800b0100-error.html). In any case I will prepare a complete disk image of my C:\

Comment: Ok, I recovered all files listed in CBS.log, I relaunched Windows 7 Service Pack 1 for x64 from the Control Panel and ... after 45 minutes I got Windows 7 SP1 installed. Now I'm waiting to complete installation  of additional updates.